# VS2008 Team Suite working with VS2010 TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

Can I use Visual Studio 2008 Team Suite to work with Visual Studio 2010 Team Foundation Server? What are the functions that will not work?

Comment: I only have anecdotal evidence so this is just a comment, but I believe that you can do this.

Comment: I have been using VS2008 with TFS2010 since Beta 2 of TFS2010 was released last year without any issues. There are restrictions which apply as new functionality isn't possible with the older client. It is possible though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That googles well.  Here's the [best hit](http://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2009/11/05/updating-visual-studio-2008-in-order-to-work-with-tfs-2010.aspx).  Be sure to carefully read the "Unsupported scenarios" list.

Comment: Thanks, the blog is short enough to get the quickest answer.